# Column populated with table string occurrences joined to original SQL table

Tags: sql, join, presto, trino

I would like to query for a table that shows me my raw data as well as a column that counts the occurrences of a value ('ID') subject to a conditions ('Type' NOT LIKE '%jack%')

| ID | big | med | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | x | 1 | lumber_jack |
| 1002 | y | 2 | jack_knife |
| 1001 | z | 3 | peter_pan |
| 1005 | a | 4 | rock_star |
| 1005 | b | 5 | paper_hands |
| 1007 | c | 6 | to_the_moon |

Example: 2 occurrences of ID = 1001 but only one that does not contain '%jack%' in 'Type' column therefore count = 1

My desired output is:

| ID | big | med | Type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | x | 1 | lumber_jack | 1 |
| 1002 | y | 2 | jack_knife | 0 |
| 1001 | z | 3 | peter_pan | 1 |
| 1005 | a | 4 | rock_star | 2 |
| 1005 | b | 5 | paper_hands | 2 |
| 1007 | c | 6 | to_the_moon | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using window function:

```
select * , sum(case when Type NOT LIKE '%jack%' then 1 end) over (partition by ID)  as count 
from table
```

Comment: Yes this worked really nicely, thanks so much!